# How to add an NSColorWell to an NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, custom-controls, nstableview, nscell

Is it possible to wrap an `NSColorWell` as an `NSCell` so I can add it to an `NSTableView`? If not, is there another solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open-source implementation called [LVColorWellCell](http://ringce.com/code/Cocoa/lvcolorwellcell). This only works with garbage collection, though.